# Ternary string comparison in Razor view is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor view where I'm trying to apply a ternary to make an item in a select field show as selected. For some reason, the string comparison in the ternary doesn't appear to be working even though the value of the string in the model matched the string I am comparing against.

Here is what I'm trying to do;

```
<select name="accountStatus" class="form-control w-100">
<option>Any</option>
<option value="ACTIVE" @(Model.AccountStatus == "ACTIVE" ? "selected" : "")>Active only</option>
<option value="INACTIVE" @(Model.AccountStatus == "INACTIVE" ? "selected" : "")>Inactive only</option>
</select>
```

I have confirmed that the value of Model.AccountStatus is 'ACTIVE', but the select is defaulting to 'Any'.

I have outputted the value of AccountStatus on the page to confirm that it is indeed correct using.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've confirmed that it's 'ACTIVE' and not 'ACTIVE ' or 'Active' correct? You could also do Model.AccountStatus.Equals("ACTIVE",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) to avoid any casing issues. Or even call Trim() before you do the comparison. I really don't think this is the ternary but an issue with the string comparison itself and the data maybe not coming out exactly as we think (easy to miss the trailing space for example)

Comment: Yep, I've confirmed that the value is 'ACTIVE', all capitals, with no spaces anywhere in the string. I tried your suggestion, that didn't work. I have however switched to use a SelectList instead, and this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `null` from your ternary instead of empty string. If the attribute's value is null, Razor will remove it automatically, but since you're setting it to something, even if it's just an empty string, it will persist.

You could change you code to:

```
<select name="accountStatus" class="form-control w-100">
<option>Any</option>
<option value="ACTIVE" selected="@((Model.AccountStatus =="ACTIVE") ? "selected" : null )">Active only</option>
<option value="INACTIVE" selected="@((Model.AccountStatus =="INACTIVE") ? "selected" : null )">Inactive only</option>
</select>
```